# jQuery math returns 0.0 but 0.00 is required

Tags: jquery, math, numbers, dollar-sign

I have the following function:

```
function checktotal(){
    total = currentproduct["priceperticket"] * $("#qtyselect").val();
    $("span#totalprice").html("$"+total);
}
```

and when it has a total of 65.50 it returns 65.5.

I don't know if I need to do a length or split at the `.` and then join a 0 or what to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `'toFixed'` method:

```
$("span#totalprice").html("$"+total.toFixed(2));
```

Answer (score 1):

number.toString(),  then rpad
http://ksblog.org/index.php?q=lpad-rpad-functions-javascript&id=44

Comment: Using the built-in `.toFixed()` function is a much better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.toFixed(2)`. See below,

```
function checktotal(){
    total = parseFloat(currentproduct["priceperticket"] * $("#qtyselect").val()).toFixed(2);
    $("span#totalprice").html("$"+total);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the nature of your project, you may want to consider using [accounting.js](http://josscrowcroft.github.com/accounting.js/).

A simple way to accomplish your goal is to use the [`.toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/ToFixed) function which will render the number with 2 decimal places, but you should also check for `NaN` values before doing the arithmetic.

```
function checktotal(){
    var price = parseFloat(currentproduct["priceperticket"]);
    var quantity = parseFloat($("#qtyselect").val());

    // Check if price or quantity is not a number
    // IF so, clear the price display (or do something else)
    if (isNaN(price) || isNaN(quantity))
      $("span#totalprice").html("");

    var total = (price * quantity).toFixed(2);
    $("span#totalprice").html("$" + total);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check this

```
   parseFloat("65.5").toFixed(2)
```